# Simpler for of Euler-Maruyama or am I missing something

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

The stochastic part of the Euler-Maruyama method is often written with random increments with zero mean and variance $\Delta t$. For example for the SDE (drift diffusion)
$$ 
dX(T)=\delta dt + sdW(t)
$$
one could simulate this as
$$
X(t+\Delta t)=X(t) + \delta\Delta t+\Delta W,
$$
where $\Delta W\sim Normal(0,s^2\Delta t)$.

However, wouldn't this be equivalent to the (maybe simpler form)
$$
X(t+\Delta t) = X(t) + \Delta X(t)\Delta t
$$
with $\Delta X(t) \sim \cdot Normal(\delta, s^2)$, since here the $\Delta t$ scales both the variance as well as the mean. Or is there something that I am missing and these two forms are not equivalent? I feel, that this is much closer to the original Euler method on which the Euler-Maruyama method is based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent. The whole point of separating the study of classical ODEs from SDEs is that the term $\Delta W$ has size in the order of $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ and not $\Delta t$ (see the standard deviation of $\Delta W$), so you cannot write the discretization using the classical Euler method with $\Delta X$ independent of $\Delta t$.

Now, let me clarify where your mistake is. You basically say that
$$
\Delta X\Delta t = \delta\Delta t+\Delta W 
$$
which is incorrect. Since $\Delta X \sim \mathcal{N}(\delta,s^2)$ (as you defined) then $\Delta X = \delta + w$ where $w\sim \mathcal{N}(0,s^2)$. Now
$$
\Delta X\Delta t = \delta \Delta t+ w\Delta t
$$
and we are left to compute the variance of $w\Delta t$ which is $\mathbb{E}\{(w\Delta t)^2\}=\mathbb{E}\{w^2\}\Delta t^2 = s^2\Delta t^2$ and not $s^2\Delta t$ as $\Delta W$ had. This is where the $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ vs $\Delta t$ matters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I think I got where I went wrong. It seems I messed up Var and SD for a moment. So I think one could write it instead as $\Delta X\sim \mathcal{N}(\delta,s^2/\Delta t)$ (which should have been the correct backtranslation from my code `rnorm(1,delta*dt,sqrt(dt))`)?